# Mongo Change Streams not returning all the updates to the collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

I am trying to use Change Streams to lookup/monitor the changes to a mongo collection.

```
cursor = db.collection.watch(full_document='updateLookup')
document = next(cursor)
print document['documentKey']
```

While using updateMany to update multiple documents at once, I'm not able to see all the changed documents. However if I update one at a time, then I see each change in the Stream.

```
db.collection.updateMany( {"contacts.firstName": "XXXXXX"}, { $set: {"LocationId" : 11111} } )

{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 77, "modifiedCount" : 77 }
```

Results:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('580694d039811a468b96fc7b')}
{u'_id': ObjectId('58aeebed39811a468b974e97')}
{u'_id': ObjectId('59efe28b39811a468b97b9cc')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Need to iterate through the change stream cursor to get all updates.

```
while True:
    cursor = db.collection.watch(full_document='updateLookup')
    while cursor:
        print next(cursor)['documentKey']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](http://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-36-change-streams.html) very informative, and they did mention your situation:

> Operations that affect multiple documents, like insertMany(), generate one 'change' event per affected document. For example, if you call insertMany() with 2 documents, you'll get two 'change' events. In general, each 'change' event describes changes to a single document.